# Left padding with 0 in a string

Tags: r, string, gsub

I'm trying to clean up some data. This should be pretty simple, but I'm struggling to figure this out. I'd like to left pad 1-9 in a string, but I don't want to change the string if the number is greater than 10.  I've been using `gsub()` but I haven't been able to find a way to tell R to ignore a value of anything comes after the 1 in the pattern I'd like to replace.

```
df = data.frame("col1" = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10),
                "col2" = c("test 1", "test 2", "test 3", "test 14", "test 15", "test 16", "test 17", "test 18", "test 19", "test 20" ))

> df
   col1    col2
1     1  test 1
2     2  test 2
3     3  test 3
4     4 test 14
5     5 test 15
6     6 test 16
7     7 test 17
8     8 test 18
9     9 test 19
10   10 test 20

# This is what I've been trying without much luck
test <- df %>% 
  mutate(col2 = gsub("test 1", "test 01", col2))

# My result
> test
   col1     col2
1     1  test 01
2     2   test 2
3     3   test 3
4     4 test 014
5     5 test 015
6     6 test 016
7     7 test 017
8     8 test 018
9     9 test 019
10   10  test 20


----------------
> desired
   col1    col2
1     1 test 01
2     2 test 02
3     3 test 03
4     4 test 14
5     5 test 15
6     6 test 16
7     7 test 17
8     8 test 18
9     9 test 19
10   10 test 20
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could extract the numeric part with `parse_number`, use `sprintf` to pad the 2 digit while pasting the prefix 'test'

```
library(dplyr)    
df %>% 
    mutate(col2 = sprintf('test %02d', readr::parse_number(col2)))
```

-output

```
#   col1    col2
#1     1 test 01
#2     2 test 02
#3     3 test 03
#4     4 test 14
#5     5 test 15
#6     6 test 16
#7     7 test 17
#8     8 test 18
#9     9 test 19
#10   10 test 20
```

---

Or using `sub`, capture the digit (`\\d`) at the end (`$`) of the string followed by a space (`\\s`), in the replacement, add a space followed by 0 and the backreference (`\\1`) of the captured group

```
with(df, sub("\\s(\\d)$", " 0\\1", col2))
#[1] "test 01" "test 02" "test 03" "test 14" "test 15" 
#[6] "test 16" "test 17" "test 18" "test 19" "test 20"
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, using `str_pad` and negative lookahead `(?!\\d)` to limit padding to single digits:

```
 library(stringr)
 str_pad(sub("test (\\d)(?!\\d)","test 0\\1", df$col2, perl = T), width = 2, side = "left", pad = "0")
 [1] "test 01"      "test 02"      "test 03"      "test test 14" "test test 15" "test test 16"
 [7] "test test 17" "test test 18" "test test 19" "test test 20"
```